# Google fonts do not work on css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the following html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                <h2 class="uppercase claim claim-light slash headline-standard">Our Playbook</h2>
                <div class="paragraph">
                    Blah blah blah blah
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                <h2 class="uppercase claim claim-light slash headline-standard">The Special Sauce
                </h2>

                <p class="paragraph">
                    blah blah blah
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to use a google font on class paragraph so I have this css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);

.paragraph{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(48,48,48,1);
    color:#FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:2pt;
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1;

}
```

Any other css attribute works perfectly but not the font-family, any idea why this is happening?

I tried even to include it like:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;` It's over riding the first font-family you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/pkFHd)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);

.paragraph{
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(48,48,48,1);
    color:#FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:2pt;
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:1;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Into your CSS class `.paragraph`, the `font-family` define two times.

> The CSS rule that applies to a particular element or class is the the
>   last rule defined in your CSS.

So, `font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;` It's over riding the `font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;`

Try -

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);

.paragraph{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(48,48,48,1);
    color:#FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing:1pt;
    word-spacing:2pt;
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-align:left;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rDkRm/)